# I deleted database of my wp website and wordpress asks to be reinstalled

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I deleted database and db user of my WP website. My website stopped working.

I opened wpadmin.php and created database and user according to info in it.

Now when I try to open my website it redirects to 
http://iiuischoolsryk.com/wp-admin/install.php

What should I do now? Should I proceed to Installation?

PS:

1. Although hosting provider is my best friend, he is not available to help
2. I have access to Cpanel, phpMYADMIN.
3. I have complete installation files of that particular wp theme.

Answer (score 0):

All your previous data, unless backed up, is totally gone. You'll have your theme and plugins still in their directories, but no pages, posts, etc.

To get back to having a blank wordpress installation, do the following.

1. Create a new MySQL database, via phpMyAdmin if you like.
2. Create a new MySQL user, with password, and assign them permissions
   to the database created in step 1.
3. Now run the 5 minute WordPress install with the database name, user
   name, and passwordyou've just created.

Comment: You might be able to pull content from either Google or Wayback Machine. For Google, do a search like "site:example.com" (replace with your domain) and for every page use the little down triangle to choose "Cached." This will give you their last copy of the content; if you're lucky you might be able to save your text and images. Similar on Wayback Machine (www.archive.org), search for your homepage, and see if they have a copy saved - then search for each individual page.

Comment: @WebElaine that's true, desperate times call for desperate measures :)